# $(window).bind('load' ... ); not triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs

I'm currently working at making a web application only open one instance. This is being done with cookies that are being set/checked when the app is loaded and removed when the app is closed. My logic for setting the cookies I've already worked out, but I'm having a problem getting it to trigger.

My web app is built using require.js and backbone.js. In my main.js file I'm binding my calls to my single instance logic to the `load` and `unload` events as can be seen below.

```
requirejs(['jquery', 'router', 'singleInstance'], function ($, Router, SingleInstance) {
    //TODO fix load event is not triggering...
    $(window).bind('load', function () {
        SingleInstance.setSingleInstance();
    });
    $(window).bind('unload', function () {
        SingleInstance.removeSingleInstace();
    });
```

By setting break points on the calls to `setSingleInstance()` and `removeSingleInstance()` I have found that `removeSingleInstance()` gets called as would be expected with unload events, but `setSingleInstance()` is not ever getting called. How can I bind this call to the `load` event?

Comment: Don't see any `$(window).bind('load' … )`

Comment: `$(document).ready(function () {
        SingleInstance.setSingleInstance(); })`

Comment: I apologize, I've been trying to debug and didn't get the last change reverted properly. It's fixed now

Comment: You're doing `$(window).bind('ready')` and not `$(window).bind('load')`.

Comment: @JqueryKing Your code does work, but if I could I would like to use the window `load` event for style reasons to match the `unload`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that by the time you bind the listener, the window has already loaded, thus not triggering the callback function. If it does not have side effects, just call `SingleInstance.setSingleInstance();` immediately in your requirejs callback.

> I would like to use the window load event for style reasons to match the unload

Well, it's blocking your code from working.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I was under the impression that being as I don't initialize my router until later in the code the window load event would not fire until after my binding.

Comment: `$(window).load()` is different than `$(document).ready()`: the `$(document).ready()` callback function will trigger even after the event has been fired, but the callback function of `$(window).load()` won't. See this fiddle for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/pdv432w6/